# Not able to see latest release version under closed testing on play store

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have one android app on Playstore.
I want to publish a new version for which I have uploaded the one under '**Closed Testing**' on the console.
The update got reviewed but I cannot see the updated version when I check from my phone.
Below are the points Which I am already taking care of.

- Adding email under testers.
- Using the same e-mail to check the version on the play store.
- Clearing cache of the play store app.

Note:

1. I am able to see the new 'What's new?' content.
2. It is showing as 'You are beta tester etc.'

The only issue is I am unable to see/download the latest release under closed testing.

Comment: Does it have a (strictly) higher versionCode than what you have currently installed? Play will always serve the APK with the highest versionCode you are eligible for.

Comment: It was the issue. I am unsure why console do accept the builds then? Any way thanks.

Comment: Maybe you uploaded that version before you promoted the other one to production?

Comment: Another think to consider is vpn, i found that enabling vpn can block some url redirection so i need to double check my vpn domain filter